# Why doesn't "i := i + 1" give a range-check error for Integers and larger types?

Tags: delphi, range-checking

Consider:

```
{$R+}
i:= 1;
While i > 0 do
  i:= i + 1;
ShowMessage(IntToStr(i));
```

If I declare `i` as Byte, Word, Shortint or TinyInt I get a range-check error, as expected.
If I declare `i` as LongWord, Cardinal, Integer, LongInt or Int64 it just goes through the while loop and gets to show the negative or 0 value, which `i` gets when you pass the upper bound.

Does Delphi 7 not support range checking for 32-bit and 64-bit numbers?

Comment: See more on Range Checking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134658/how-to-set-default-compiler-options-for-xe2/75578536#75578536

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The operation i + 1 doesn't actually produce a range check error. The assignment operation does.

Delphi evaluates the constant '1' as an Integer and so the right hand side will produce a result that is either an Int64 or an Integer (The larger of i's type and Integer).

If we expand the line out we get the following

```
temp := i + 1 
i := temp
```

temp will either be 32 or 64 bits, and will overflow if it hits the upper bound. By the time we do the assignment, we have a perfectly valid 32 or 64bit value so there's no possibility of a range check failure if i is 32bits or more.

If i is less than 32 bits, it will raise a range check if temp is too large to fit.

For i >= 32bits, you can catch the overflow error like so:

```
{$R+,Q+}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation which helped with some direction. I did some more testing, instead adding i+1 I added i+j with both i and j of the same type. This resulted in the same problem. So I'd say the "+" operator makes the result an integer.
Strangely though: if I use Inc(i), then no matter what type I use, I don't get a rangecheck error. I found  the {$Q+} to give me an integer overflow exception.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that should have been a Q, not an O :)

Comment: So in the end I was using the wrong tool for the job and should have been looking for an overflow instead of a rangecheck.

Comment: Just linking some documentation about Q+: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=$Q

Comment: Also noting that EVERYONE should have those two options (R and Q) turned on in project's settings when in Debug mode.

Comment: @PieterB ->  It is not the = or the + operator that is doing the range/overflow checking, but some "secret" checking code that the compiler injects around those operators when the R and Q are enabled. This statement might be obvious and well known for some, but not for all - so I thought it is better to clarify it here.