# How to change Delphi XE2 default behaviour for some panes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

After switching from Delphi2007 to XE2, I'm terribly unhappy with the behaviour of some Windows/Panes.
I'm designing in the 'Default layout', it changes to the 'Debug layout' when running/debugging.
'Autosave project desktop' is set in my environment options.

For 'Default layout':

1. How can I permanently hide the structure view(pane)?
   Closing or un-pinning it does not hold between sessions.
2. How can I keep an opened group in the Tool Palette open between sessions?
   All groups are closed again when I start a new IDE session.

For 'Debug layout':

A. How can I permanently hide the call stack view(pane)?
   Closing or un-pinning it does not hold between sessions.

I have read [How to set default compiler options for XE2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134658/how-to-set-default-compiler-options-for-xe2) but that is about project options, not IDE configuration.

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Check out [`this topic`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Saving_Desktop_Layouts) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like TLama already quoted you need to save your desktop layout. This was already possibly in your Delphi 2007 IDE.

Arrange the panels the way you want to, respectively hide/pin/unpin/... them. Then click "save your current desktop" in the Desktop panel.

Same goes for debugging. Layout your debug desktop while debugging and save it. But you have to make it your default debug desktop. Goto Menu > View > Desktops > Set Debug Desktop.

I don't know if you are able to keep opened groups in the tool palette.

Comment: Thanks both, I was obviously confusing 'desktop layout' and 'project desktop'.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `View > Desktops > Set Debug Desktop` but it didn't seem to work correctly, instead what worked is `View > Desktps > Save Desktop` and then select the option `Debug Layout` in the window that appears and click `OK`.